# formula for the derivation

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $g:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions, $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ open interval. It is $F(x,g(x))= 0$ and $D_2F\not=0$. I have to deduce a formula for the derivation of g.

My try: $D_2F=F_y(x,g(x))g'(x)\not=0\Rightarrow g'(x)=\frac{1}{F_y(x,g(x))}$. It is $F(x,g(x))=0$, but'm not sure how to continue. Do you have an Idea?

Edit: Why is  $F(x,g(x))=0$ important?

Comment: Why do you think you "have to continue"? Isn't the expression you got for $\;g\;$, in terms of $\;F_y\;$ , enough?

Comment: I dont know why the condition $F(x,g(x))=0$ is necessary.  Can I find an other expression for $F_y(x,g(x))$ ?

Comment: (1) I don't know, (2) I'm not sure but perhaps what you got is as close as an explicit expression for $\;g'(x)\;$ as you can expect. Observe that there are infinite examples with infinite $\;g$'s that can easily be constructed.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it helpful to consider $G(x,y)=g^{-1}(y)-x$ and to derivate G? Maybe G=F but I'm not sure.

Comment: $F(x,g(x)) = 0$ is important because you differentiate $h(x) = F(x,g(x))$. $$0 = h'(x) = D_1F(x,g(x)) + D_2F(x,g(x)) \cdot g'(x).$$

Comment: ok, this means $D_1F(x,g(x))=0$ and therefore $D_2F(x,g(x))g'(x))=0$ ? But this contradicts $F_y(x,g(x))g'(x)\not=0$?